Real Commutant Algebra of a Set of Matrices
Suppose I have a collection of $N\times N$ real, symmetric matrices $R_1, R_2, \dots$ and I want to find their orthogonal commutant---that is, the group of real, orthogonal matrices that commute with all of them. We can write this as:
$$
H = \left\{Q \in SO(N)  \mid \forall n, [R_n,Q] = 0\right\}
$$
If I were interested in the commutant among all unitary matrices, I could use the following strategy:

Replace $H$ with its Lie algebra $\mathfrak h = \left\{X \in \mathfrak u(N) \mid \forall n, [R_n,X] = 0\right\}$. This is the same basic problem, but the elements of $\mathfrak h$ are anti-Hermitian, which will make the next steps easier.

Take the closure of $\{R_n\}$ under commutators, which (with an extra factor of $i$) gives us a representation $\rho$ of some Lie algebra $\mathfrak r$. By the Jacobi identity, this algebra has the same commutant as the original $\{R_n\}$.

$\rho$ must be completely reducible, so there is a basis in which $\rho=\rho_1 \oplus \rho_2 \oplus \dots$. We can choose this basis such that equivalent representations are manifestly equal.

Rewrite $X \in \mathfrak h$ as a block matrix in this basis:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
X_{11} & X_{12} & \dots\\
X_{21} & X_{22} & \\
\vdots & & \ddots
\end{pmatrix},
$$
so the commutation identity reduces to
$$
\rho_i X_{ij} = X_{ij} \rho_j
$$
(note that these indices are not implicitly summed over). By Schur's lemma, $X_{ij}$ is proportional to the identity if $\rho_i = \rho_j$ and $0$ otherwise.

When the dust settles, we obtain:
$$
\mathfrak{h} = \bigoplus_{j} \mathfrak{u}(m_j)
$$
$$
H = \prod_j U(m_j)
$$
where $m_j$ is the multiplicity of the representation $\rho_j$.


However, if I try to do the same thing for real matrices, I run into the following problems:

$\mathbb R$ is not closed, so Schur's lemma no longer guarantees that $X \propto 1$ when $X\rho = \rho X$.

The commutator of two symmetric matrices is anti-symmetric, so I can't build a Lie algebra out of $R_n$ without making it noncompact (which isn't insurmountable, but makes the rep theory much more complicated).


How can I go about fixing this?
If it helps, this problem arose when trying to determine the symmetry group of a quantum field theory with Majorana fermions, and all $R$ are known to have the same spectrum.

Instead of working with a Lie algebra you can work with the real associative subalgebra $R \subseteq M_N(\mathbb{R})$ generated by the $R_i$, which also has the same commutant and orthogonal commutant. Because the $R_i$ are symmetric, this real subalgebra is closed under taking transposes, so it is a real $C^{\ast}$-algebra. The abstract definition of these things is a little tricky but the concrete definition (a norm-closed $^{\ast}$-subalgebra of bounded operators on a real Hilbert space) works fine here.

Proposition: Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real Hilbert space and $A \subseteq B(V)$ be a real $C^{\ast}$-algebra acting on $H$ (so $A$ is a norm-closed $^{\ast}$-subalgebra). Then $V$ is completely reducible as an $A$-module.

The proof is the same as over $\mathbb{C}$, you take orthogonal complements of invariant subspaces. So, in our setting, it follows that the action of $R$ on $\mathbb{R}^N$ is completely reducible, meaning we can write $\mathbb{R}^N$ as a direct sum of irreducibles.
Schur's lemma over $\mathbb{R}$ says that if $V_i$ is finite-dimensional and irreducible then $\text{End}(V_i)$ is a finite-dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, hence by the Frobenius theorem is isomorphic to either $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$; these are sometimes called real, complex, or quaternionic representations (there is a very closely related but not quite identical classification of complex irreducible representations, which is sometimes confusing). It follows that if we write $\mathbb{R}^N \cong \bigoplus_i V_i^{n_i}$ as a direct sum of irreducibles then
$$\text{End}_A(\mathbb{R}^N) \cong \prod_i M_{n_i}(D_i)$$
where $D_i = \text{End}(V_i) \cong \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$, and accordingly the corresponding group of orthogonal automorphisms is a product of copies of either $O(n_i), U(n_i)$, or $Sp(n_i)$ depending on whether $D_i$ is $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$.

Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

@Matt: you're welcome! As a fun additional note, it's actually not even necessary for the $R_i$ to be symmetric. The orthogonal commutant doesn't change if we toss in all the transposes of the $R_i$ (not true of the commutant!), so in fact to compute the orthogonal commutant of an arbitrary set of matrices we can pass to the $C^{\ast}$-algebra they generate WLOG.

This also explains why the Lie algebra trick works over $\mathbb{C}$; finite-dimensional $C^{\ast}$-algebras (real or complex) are semisimple, so are finite products of matrix algebras (over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$), and we can find Lie algebras of skew-symmetric matrices inside these. It just happens that over $\mathbb{C}$ this can be done very directly.
